# How do i use cloudflare without chaging nameserver

Tags: proxy, web-hosting, cloudflare

I am trying to setup Cloudflare on my site, and I am not allowed to modify my nameserver for company policy reason.

Is there a way for me to do this with the free plan? (I know business plan allows CNAME setup)

Maybe point my IP to cloudflare and have cloudflare go to the actual IP when it needs to?

Thank in advance.

Comment: When you say you are "trying to setup Cloudflare on [your] site", what is the reason for setting it up? Web acceleration, DDoS protection, workers?

Comment: @AaronQueenan Yes, mainly for Web acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use Cloudflare without changing the authoritative nameservers to Cloudflare nameservers, is to use Cloudflare hosting partners such as Siteground, Bluehost, Liquidweb etc. 
However, you will most likely need to change the authoritative nameservers to your hosting partner's nameservers because they are actually using CNAME Setup on their end.

Comment: I am not allowed to touch my nameserver, this approach will not work for my situation, unfortunately.

Comment: Then you should give up Cloudflare. Use other CDN providers which are not using reverse proxy technology.